# how to append object method output in a list?

Tags: python, list, oop

I am trying to append an object method inside a list:

1. First, the class is defined:

```
class OBJECT():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name='Object'
        
    def transformation_function(self, x, y):   
        z=[]
        if x=='apple':
            z=x+'-'+y
            return
        elif x=='banana':
            z=x+'-'+y
            return 
        else:
            return
        
        return z
```

2. Apply the object method in a for-loop structure:

```
# define inputs
fruits=['mango', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana']
ids=['A001', 'A002']

if __name__=="__main__":
    
# initialize object 
 an_object=OBJECT()

 list1=[]

 for fruit in fruits:
     for id in ids:
         
        #print('id: {} and fruit: {}'.format(id, fruit))
        
        an_object.transformation_function(x=id, y=fruit)
        list1.append(an_object.transformation_function)  # here I try to catch z output from class method
        
        
print(list1)
```

The output consists on a list of all possible combinations between iterated elements, while expected output is a list of `z` elements defined inside the object transformation-method.

```
['apple-A001', 'apple-A002', 'banana-A001', 'banana-A002']
```

What am I missing? How could I possibly subscript this class method?

Comment: You never execute `return z` because all the `if` conditions end with `return`.

Comment: The result you should be getting with this code is a list of 8 `None` values, not al the combinations.

Comment: _"What am I missing?"_ 1. You never return anything from `transformation_function()`. 2. Even if you did, you never store that return value anywhere when you call `an_object.transformation_function()`. 3. You append the _function object_ to the list, you seem to want to append the return value. 4. You don't really need an object to do this - a standalone function would work fine. 5. `id()` is a predefined function in python. Naming a variable `id` shadows the inbuilt `id()` function.

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez  you exchanged the value of x=id and y=fruit while passing it should be x= fruit and y=id. I posted the correct code with some other corrections. You may check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation function needs to return the strings it's concatenating. It's not returning anything because you immediately return after assigning `z`, and never get to `return z` at the end.

```
class OBJECT():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.name='Object'
        
    def transformation_function(self, x, y):   
        if x=='apple':
            return x+'-'+y
        elif x=='banana':
            return x+'-'+y
        else:
            return
```

If the resulting list should only contain the results of transformation when it concatenated something, you need to check the value before appending to the list. Use a variable for this.

You also had the arguments to `transformation_functions` backwards. The fruit should be `x`, not `y`.

```
for fruit in fruits:
     for prefix in ids:        
        z = an_object.transformation_function(y=prefix, x=fruit)
        if z:
            list1.append(z)
```

Comment: thanks @Barmar, however the final list is an empty list, how could I catch the results of transformation when `x='apple'` and `x='banana'` into `list1`?

Comment: You had the arguments to the transformation function backwards. I've fixed that now.

Comment: You should use better variable names than `x` and `y`, this type of mistake will be less likely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I made a few necessary changes to get to your desired output:

```
class OBJECT():

   def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Object'

def transformation_function(self, x, y):
     z = []

     if x == 'apple':
       return x + '-' + y

     elif x == 'banana':
       return x + '-' + y


fruits = ['mango', 'apple', 'grape', 'banana']
ids = ['A001', 'A002']

if __name__ == "__main__":

# initialize object
an_object = OBJECT()

list1 = []

for fruit in fruits:
    for id in ids:
        # print('id: {} and fruit: {}'.format(id, fruit))

        result=an_object.transformation_function(x=fruit, y=id)
        if result != None:
         list1.append(result)  # here I try to catch z output from class method

print(list1)
```